# Extendable JavaScript linter

Tags: javascript, lint

I’m looking for JavaScript code linter/style checker with one particular feature - possibility to extend the default set of rules. I want to have an opportunity to declare new rule and describe it using any kind of mini-API that particular tool provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [JSCS](http://jscs.info/). It's more advanced linter than JSHint or JSLint (especially you have more presets). There are also additional rules.

Moreover, there is a [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) which is similar to JSCS but probably it's easier to write own rules (there is a developer guide on webpage). It requires Node.js/io.js and running on Windows/Mac/Linux.

Comment: thanks, ESlint turns out to be an awesome piece of software which is indeed extendable in a very nicely fashion.